# Render a list of all translatable strings that appear in a page / node?

Tags: 7, hooks, transliteration

I am looking for a PHP code / Drupal 7 hook which provides a list of all translatable strings that appear in the displayed page or node (i.e. all `t('strings')` with their id's).

**Update**

I need that list as an array for admin / moderator usage only in order to render links to string translation path (within node view page) so it becomes easier to translate those particular strings which appear in a given page.

I have inspected Drupal's 7 API for a function that provides such a list but could not find one yet.

Comment: Notice that you are merely describing what you want to achieve, without asking any explicit question. (The question title doesn't count ask explicit question.) To ask a question you also need to tell us what you tried, why it didn't work as expected, what documentation you read, and what you didn't understand from it, for example. Notice also that we don't provide code on request.